# Why does importing from random in python give me back unused import statement?

Tags: python, import

When I type for ex:

```
from random import shuffle
```

I get:
Unused import statement 'from random import shuffle'
in return and the letter go grey. Can anybody diagnose?

I tried "from random import shuffle" and was expecting to be able to use shuffle

Comment: because you did import the function shuffle from the library random but you did not use it in your code. so the IDE color it with grey

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Would you put the rest of code? What IDE do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the code I think that the error description is correct. Your import is unused. That means that you imported it but in the actual script the shuffle function was never accessed.

Try using it in your code:

```
from random import shuffle

my_shuffled_number = shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

print(my_shuffled_number)
```

This small script makes use of the import function.